# Unknown provider: InactivityMonitorProvider when Running Karma

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to run Karma on my angularJS application. I receive the following error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: InactivityMonitorProvider <- InactivityMonitor <- logger <- $exceptionHandler <- $rootScope <- $translate
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/unpr?p0=InactivityMonitorProvider%20%3C-%20InactivityMonitor%20%3C-%20logger%20%3C-%20%24exceptionHandler%20%3C-%20%24rootScope%20%3C-%20%24translate
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: InactivityMonitorProvider <- InactivityMonitor <- logger <- $exceptionHandler <- $rootScope <- $translate
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/unpr?p0=InactivityMonitorProvider%20%3C-%20InactivityMonitor%20%3C-%20logger%20%3C-%20%24exceptionHandler%20%3C-%20%24rootScope%20%3C-%20%24translat
```

Did anyone encountered this problem?

Comment: Most likely you are not including this external dependency in your unit test.
Your website might work because some other modules includes this but in unit test, you are loading each module independently so they need to have dependency on all external modules

Comment: What is the name of the module where `InactivityMonitor` is defined? You probably need to add a `beforeEach(module('inactivityMonitorModule'))` call.